# How to look for an element in a indefinite list of lists in Flutter

Tags: flutter, loops, dart, nested, nested-lists

I'm developing an application using Flutter.
I need to show a list where every item may expand and have another list with the same structure as the above.

This is an example JSON of what I'm working with:

```
[
  {
    "item": {
      "childrenCount": 2,
      "id": "ID1",
      "name": "name 1",
      "parentId": null
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "item": {
          "childrenCount": 0,
          "id": "ID3",
          "name": "name 3",
          "parentId": "ID1"
        },
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "item": {
          "childrenCount": 4,
          "id": "ID4",
          "name": "name 4",
          "parentId": "ID1"
        },
        "children": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "childrenCount": 0,
      "id": "ID2",
      "name": "name 2",
      "parentId": null
    },
    "children": []
  }
]
```

In the example I would draw 2 container, one for ID1 and one of ID2.
In the first Container I would draw 2 containers, one for ID3 and one for ID4.
When I click on this last container I have to call an API to get the informations about its 4 childrens.
Then as I get the response I would add those children to their parent children list.

My question is how to parse all this object the get to the right item to fill its children.

Right now I'm parsing the first level like this:

```
childrenCatalogResponseData.forEach((item) => catalog
                    .firstWhere(
                      (element) => element.item!.id == event.parentId,
                    )
                    .children!
                    .add(CatalogItemView(item, []))),
```

But this can't be used to look for parentId past the first level of nesting.
There's a smart way to pick the right item inside the tree X level inside?

Any help is appreciated!

(I don't know if I explained myself well, in case feel free to make questions)